# How can I draw a card view with half circle at the left and the right using UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibezierpath

I want to draw a card view with half circle at the left and the right using UIBezierPath like the image below.

[image]

This is my code for the custom card view class

```
class CustomCardView : UIView
{
  // init the view with a rectangular frame
  override init(frame: CGRect)
  {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  }
  // init the view by deserialisation
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  }
  /// override the draw(_:) to draw your own view
  ///
  /// Default implementation - `rectangular view`
  ///
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
  {
    // Card view corner radius
    let cardRadius = CGFloat(10)
    // Button slot arc radius
    let circleSlotRadius = CGFloat(20)
    
    // Card view frame dimensions
    let viewSize = self.bounds.size
    // Effective height of the view
    let effectiveViewHeight = viewSize.height //- buttonSlotRadius
      
    // Get a path to define and traverse
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    // Shift origin to left corner of top straight line
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: 0))
    
      // MARK: top line
      // top line
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width - cardRadius, y: 0))
      // top-right corner arc
      path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
            x: viewSize.width - cardRadius,
            y: cardRadius
        ),
        radius: cardRadius,
        startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 3 / 2),
        endAngle: CGFloat(0),
        clockwise: true
      )
      
    // MARK: right line
    // right half of right line
    path.addLine(
      to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width, y: effectiveViewHeight / 4)
    )
      
      path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
          x: viewSize.width,
          y: effectiveViewHeight / 4 - circleSlotRadius
        ),
        radius: circleSlotRadius,
        startAngle: CGFloat(0),
        endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2),
        clockwise: true
      )
      
      // circle-slot line
      path.addLine(
        to: CGPoint(
          x: viewSize.width + circleSlotRadius,
          y: effectiveViewHeight / 4 + circleSlotRadius
        )
      )
      // circle left arc
      path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
          x: viewSize.width,
          y: effectiveViewHeight / 4 + circleSlotRadius
        ),
        radius: circleSlotRadius,
        startAngle: CGFloat(0),
        endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
        clockwise: false
      )
      
      
      
      // left half of right line
      path.addLine(
        to: CGPoint(x: viewSize.width, y: effectiveViewHeight)
      )
      // right-left corner arc
      path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
          x: viewSize.width - cardRadius,
          y: effectiveViewHeight
        ),
        radius: cardRadius,
        startAngle: CGFloat(0),
        endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
        clockwise: true
      )

      // MARK: bottom line
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: effectiveViewHeight))

      // bottom-left corner arc
      path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(
          x: cardRadius,
          y: effectiveViewHeight - cardRadius
        ),
        radius: cardRadius,
        startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2),
        endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
        clockwise: true
      )

    // MARK: left line
      // left line
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cardRadius))
      // top-left corner arc
      path.addArc(
        withCenter: CGPoint(x: cardRadius, y: cardRadius),
        radius: cardRadius,
        startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi),
        endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 3),
        clockwise: true
      )
    
      
      
    // close path join to origin
    path.close()
    // Set the background color of the view
    UIColor.gray.set()
    path.fill()
  }
}
```

Comment: You should have described how your code works, what the errors/exceptions if any, and what is not working as supposed. Please follow [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not too far off, but you got a bit confused with your arc centers and clockwise directions...

Couple things that you may find helpful:

1 - if you're not going to use the full bounds, define the desired rectangle and use `.minX`, `.maxX`, `.minY` and `.maxY`. So you might do this:

```
var effectiveRect: CGRect = bounds
effectiveRect.height -= 50.0
```

2 - Define your arc centers using logical naming, such as:

```
    // define the corner arc centers
    let topLeftCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.minX + cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.minY + cardRadius)
    let topRightCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.maxX - cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.minY + cardRadius)
    let bottomRightCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.maxX - cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.maxY - cardRadius)
    let bottomLeftCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.minX + cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.maxY - cardRadius)
    
    // and the slot arc centers
    let leftSlotCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.minX, y: effectiveRect.midY)
    let rightSlotCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.maxX, y: effectiveRect.midY)
```

3 - To make it easier to visualize the arc angles, define them like the hours on a round clock... :

```
    let clock3: CGFloat = .pi * 0.0
    let clock6: CGFloat = .pi * 0.5
    let clock9: CGFloat = .pi * 1.0
    let clock12: CGFloat = .pi * 1.5
```

then you can think in terms of *"I want this arc to start at 12 o'clock and end at 3 o'clock"*

Here is your class, updated:

```
class CustomCardView : UIView
{

     override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        
        // Card view corner radius
        let cardRadius = CGFloat(10)
        
        // Button slot arc radius
        let circleSlotRadius = CGFloat(20)
        
        // in case you don't want to use the full bounds
        //  adjust the rect here
        var effectiveRect: CGRect = bounds
        
        // for example, if you are going to put something else at the bottom
        //  you coud do:
        //effectiveRect.height -= buttonSlotRadius
        
        // let's define the corner arc centers
        let topLeftCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.minX + cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.minY + cardRadius)
        let topRightCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.maxX - cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.minY + cardRadius)
        let bottomRightCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.maxX - cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.maxY - cardRadius)
        let bottomLeftCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.minX + cardRadius, y: effectiveRect.maxY - cardRadius)
        
        // and the slot arc centers
        let leftSlotCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.minX, y: effectiveRect.midY)
        let rightSlotCenter: CGPoint = .init(x: effectiveRect.maxX, y: effectiveRect.midY)
        
        // to make it easier to visualize the arc angles,
        //  define them like the hours on a round clock
        let clock3: CGFloat = .pi * 0.0
        let clock6: CGFloat = .pi * 0.5
        let clock9: CGFloat = .pi * 1.0
        let clock12: CGFloat = .pi * 1.5
        
        // Get a path to define and traverse
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        // Shift origin to left corner of top straight line
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: topLeftCenter.x, y: effectiveRect.minY))
        
        // MARK: top line
        // top line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topRightCenter.x, y: effectiveRect.minY))
        
        // top-right corner arc
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: topRightCenter,
            radius: cardRadius,
            startAngle: clock12,
            endAngle: clock3,
            clockwise: true
        )
        
        // MARK: right line
        // top half of right line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: effectiveRect.maxX, y: rightSlotCenter.y - circleSlotRadius))
        
        // right-side slot arc
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: rightSlotCenter,
            radius: circleSlotRadius,
            startAngle: clock12,
            endAngle: clock6,
            clockwise: false
        )
        
        // bottom half of right line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: effectiveRect.maxX, y: bottomRightCenter.y))
        
        // bottom-right corner arc
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: bottomRightCenter,
            radius: cardRadius,
            startAngle: clock3,
            endAngle: clock6,
            clockwise: true
        )
        
        // bottom line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCenter.x, y: effectiveRect.maxY))
        
        // bottom-left corner arc
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: bottomLeftCenter,
            radius: cardRadius,
            startAngle: clock6,
            endAngle: clock9,
            clockwise: true
        )
        
        // bottom half of left line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: effectiveRect.minX, y: leftSlotCenter.y + circleSlotRadius))
        
        // left-side slot arc
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: leftSlotCenter,
            radius: circleSlotRadius,
            startAngle: clock6,
            endAngle: clock12,
            clockwise: false
        )
        
        // top half of left line
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: effectiveRect.minX, y: topLeftCenter.y))
        
        // top-left corner arc
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: topLeftCenter,
            radius: cardRadius,
            startAngle: clock9,
            endAngle: clock12,
            clockwise: true
        )
        
        // close path join to origin
        path.close()
        
        // Set the background color of the path
        UIColor.gray.set()
        path.fill()
    }
    
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]